# Is it possible to open a regular monetdb database directory with monetdb/e?

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to point monetdb/e to a regular monetdb database directory (version 11.37.7 (Jun2020)) and getting a 254 returned by `monetdbe_open()`.

Is this currently not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Also, is there an IRC channel or equivalent for monetdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work *yet* and I also don't expect it'll be included in the first release.  But it's definitely high on our list since MonetDB is in a unique position to be able to support both an embedded and server variant.

MonetDB doesn't have an IRC-like channel. Users can ask questions here on Stack Overflow, in the MonetDB [user-list](https://www.monetdb.org/mailman/listinfo/users-list), or even in the [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/).

In addition, you can directly add feature requests and bug report in the GitHub repository of [MonetDB/e (currently only for Python)](https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/MonetDBe-Python/issues).  I just added this to our [wish list](https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/MonetDBe-Python/issues/78).